# Create EDI Batch in Azure Logic App

Tags: azure, batch-processing, azure-logic-apps, edi

I'm trying to create an X12 271 with multiple "ST" segments (transaction sets) using Logic Apps.  I can create a 271 with one "ST" segment without issue.  However, it looks like I need to use the batching process to create a 271 with multiple "ST" segments.  I am successfully able to send messages to a batch configuration in my Integration Account.  However, the documentation on X12 Batch Encoding does not match the task in the logic app.  Please see below:

Batch Documentation:
[Batch Documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXUMV.jpg)

Actual Batch Screen:
[Actual Batch Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SzqMQ.jpg)

Am I on the right path to be able to create a 271 with multiple transaction sets?  If so, can someone please help me figure out what to fill in the "Items Content" and "Items MessageId" fields?  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft must have been changing something.  Last night when I clicked the small "T" it allowed me to type in json.  This morning, I tried it again and the screen a looked correct when I clicked the small "T".